# efficient ways to get fans

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I was wondering if anyone knows of ways to get fans easily or at least what I have to do to increase the amount of fans that I have at the moment? I know that doing things with a publisher helps but I would prefer not to take publishing deals if that can be avoided.

Comment: What do you have against publishing deals?  They seem to be a necessary step on the ladder from making your own small games to making your own medium games.

Comment: @bwarner I actually transitioned pretty smoothly from self-publishing small games to self-publishing medium games without the help of publishers, but to get to large games I had to release a few publisher-backed large games.

Comment: @kotekzot I went from self-published medium to self-published large games seamlessly. The only "trick" is waiting. In my case I just never had the opportunity to research large games for a lack of employees. Once I did, I was already way past the optimal fan quantity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Publishing deals might help you initially to gain fans at a faster rate. Initially getting **100K fans** becomes crucial since that **unlocks the ability to distribute Medium games on your own** without a publisher. Doing so before you have 100K fans puts penalties on your game score, which makes publishing medium games on your own not so worthwhile.

So, I would recommend taking publisher deals initially to reach 100K fans. However make sure you chose the right deals with lower rating limits. Remember, your target with publisher deals are fans, not money. Just make decent games and this should net you more fans than you usually get from making small games on your own.

Once you hit 100K fans though you can stop doing the publisher deals and create your own in-house masterpiece that will take you to the big leagues.

Also further down the line you will unlock marketing. **Use marketing to generate Hype** for your game. Hype ensures that more people get to know about your game and thus generate more sales and fans. Choose an appropriate marketing campaign during development to generate Hype for your game.

Also try to time the developement phase to coincide with M6W1(Month 6, Week 1) every year. This is when G3 happens. Make sure you get a booth and have a game in production during G3. This will generate free Hype for the game. Thus increasing the sales and fans you get from the next game.

Also the most important factor for gaining fans is the Game Score of a game. Make sure you build good games. Building and Releasing bad games will result in a loss of fans. So make sure you dont release games that are not built right(Trash them if need be). Fans are everything!

PS: Publisher deals are for a single game and do not force a long term commitement/contract.

Comment: How do you choose the right marketing campaign? Also, G3 hyps is not exactly free when you have to pay for a booth.

Comment: Unlocks is too strong a wording, you can always self-publish medium games once you unlock them.  It just doesn't recommend you do so until you have enough fans.

Comment: @kotekzot - Yes I know you pay for it, but the hype generated is far more than what you pay for in a normal Marketing campaign. A small booth costs 80K and gives you much more hype than a 150K  mktg campaign making G3 participation and the hype generation worth it.

Comment: @bwarner - Yes you can publish before 100K. But there is enough data on the wikia to suggest that self publishing medium games before reaching 100K limits/clamps your game score. So you are effectively scaling down your ratings of your medium games by a point if you publish them b4 100K fans.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done a publishing deal and I have basically got to the point where it is boring due to making to much money. You need to do the following:

- Make decent games (should be the most obvious)
- Attend all events
- Make the correct moral decisions when it comes to making decisions on random events, ie; if it asks you to help women get involved in technology, support it.
- Basically have a good team, with plenty of research and decent game engines that are capable of producing games with a rating of around 7/10 majority of the time and you will gain heaps of fans.
- Also, try not to give up when you get really low on cash. Just keep trying to produce the best quality games.

Good Luck!